Skip empty cells in range
I have code to select a specified range and paste it into an e-mail. I would like to skip copying blank cells and paste only the cells that contain data.
The range should stay the same as it is a table filled from external sources. Sometimes cells might be blank and at other times different cells will be blank. At times no cells will be blank.
I tried constants. It would then only paste the range C13:J13. This is the only row that hasn't any formulae in the cells, only text. All other cells within the range have formulae. I guess it would be best to check whether length <1 then skip.
Sub PrepareMailOffer()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next

    Set rng = Sheets("000000").Range("C12:J29").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Range("N4").Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .HTMLBody = "" & _
            RangetoHTML(rng) & _
            "" & _
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

The code works when I have no blank cells.

Is the range you try processing filtered to use xlCellTypeVisible? I mean, are there hidden rows? And are there blank cells or blank rows? If you want skipping the blank cells, how would you like the code to behave in case of such ones? Should the columns slide instead of the blank cells? Do you understand what I mean? I think it would be good to place a picture with existing (containing blank cells) and one showing how the coped range does look...

In my initial project it was supposed to be filtered but I opted to use formulae instead. I didn't update the code to reflect this change. There aren't hidden rows and there are whole blank rows. I want the code to select and paste only the rows with data and skip the blank rows

I forgot to mention that the "blank rows" contain formulae so technically they aren't blank. This is why I guess checking the length would be a better solution than SkipBlanks which doesn't work

So, you do not want skipping blank cells, which would look strange, the rest of the columns/rows should slide in one direction. Then, there are blank rows, but also **the result of formulae. This means that xlCellTypeVisible is useless and you also cannot use xlCellTypeConstants to obtain a discontinuous range skipping the blank rows. But CountBlank worksheet function should work and you can hide the blank rows and then use xlCellTypeVisible. Do you copy the range manually? Do you need making the hidden row visible again after copying the range?

You probably need to show the rest of the code, to see how you copy the range...

I have edited my question to include the full code

Please, try the next adapted code, which hides the blank rows (even with blank from formula) and process the visible cells of resulted range:
Sub PrepareMailOffer()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngH As Range, i As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

    Set ws = Sheets("000000")
    Set rng = ws.Range("C12:J29")

    'place the blank rows in a Union range and hide them, at once:
    For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
       If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng.rows(i)) = rng.Columns.count Then
           addToRange rngH, rng.rows(i).EntireRow
       End If
    Next i
    If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.Hidden = True 'hide the blank rows
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    With OutMail
        .To = Range("N4").Value
        .cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .HTMLBody = "" & _
            RangetoHTML(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) & _
            "" & _
        .Display
    End With
    
    If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhide the previous hidden rows
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub

On Error Resume Next in your code context only do not let you know what error you have, if any...
You should use the same (existing) RangetoHTML function...
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Reference Non-Blank Rows

Sub ReferenceNonBlankRows()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "000000"
    Const RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "C12:J29"
    
    ' Reference the main objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(RANGE_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Store the range's number of columns in a variable ('ColumnsCount').
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim urg As Range, rrg As Range, IsFoundNonBlankRow As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the rows ('rrg') of the range ('rg')
    ' and combine each non-blank row ('rrg') into a unioned range ('urg').
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        ' 'CountBlank' counts the number of blank cells
        ' (cells whose length is 0) in a range.
        If Application.CountBlank(rrg) < ColumnsCount Then
            If IsFoundNonBlankRow Then
                Set urg = Union(urg, rrg)
            Else
                Set urg = rrg
                IsFoundNonBlankRow = True ' never reset
            End If
        End If
    Next rrg
    
    ' Check if all rows are blank.
    If Not IsFoundNonBlankRow Then
        MsgBox "All rows in the range ""'" & ws.Name & "'!" _
            & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ are blank!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Continue using 'urg', e.g.:
    MsgBox "The rows ""'" & ws.Name & "'!" _
        & urg.Address(0, 0) & """ are not blank.", vbInformation
        
End Sub

EDIT

You could create a function using the above idea.

Function RefNonBlankRows( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ShowFailMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    
    ' Store the range's number of columns in a variable ('ColumnsCount').
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim urg As Range, rrg As Range, IsFoundNonBlankRow As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the rows ('rrg') of the range ('rg')
    ' and combine each non-blank row ('rrg') into a unioned range ('urg').
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        ' 'CountBlank' counts the number of blank cells
        ' (cells whose length is 0) in a range.
        If Application.CountBlank(rrg) < ColumnsCount Then
            If IsFoundNonBlankRow Then
                Set urg = Union(urg, rrg)
            Else
                Set urg = rrg
                IsFoundNonBlankRow = True ' never reset
            End If
        End If
    Next rrg
    
    ' Check if all rows are blank.
    If Not IsFoundNonBlankRow Then
        If ShowFailMessage Then
            MsgBox "All rows in the range ""'" & rg.Worksheet.Name & "'!" _
                & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ are blank!", vbExclamation
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Assign non-blank rows to the result of the function.
    Set RefNonBlankRows = urg

End Function


Then you could utilize it in the following way.

Sub PrepareMailOffer()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "000000"
    Const RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "C12:J29"
    Const EMAIL_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "N4"
    
    ' Reference the main objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(RANGE_ADDRESS)

    ' Reference the non-blank rows.
    Dim nbrg As Range: Set nbrg = RefNonBlankRows(rg, True)
    If nbrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim outApp As Object: Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim outMail As Object: Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
        With outMail
            .To = ws.Range(EMAIL_CELL_ADDRESS).Value
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ""
            .HTMLBody = "" _
                & "" _
                & RangetoHTML(nbrg) _
                & ""
            .Display
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub


